# Update SQL installs remotely

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, sql-server-2016

I have sys admin, local admin and remote desktop access on a bunch of Windows Server 2012 R2 VM's with SQL Server 2016 installed.

Is there a way to install an update on all of them from a single server? Basically in a scripted manner,without needing to connect to each machine manually

Comment: Right, but that would still involve connecting to the server with remote desktop and running the script on the target servers AFAIK. Looking on guidance to avoid connecting to each target server manually. (a pointer to the right Powershell API's, if they exist would be OK as well )

Comment: wsus ? or an thirdpart update management software ?